# Access already existing data Context in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I'm pretty new to the whole MVC and ASP.NET thing.

I created a new MVC application in VS2013 and are now customizing it.
Currently I am writing the administrator area when I can modify a users properties.

The whole admin section is bound to an adminController. In this controller I create a new UserContext to access the user database.
However since the application already defines a user context in the AccountController this should not be necessary.

What would be best practice to access the UserContext in my AdminController?

/edit: In a comment I explained it a bit more in detail:

> The data-context and the connection to the database already exist. This is not the problem. My problem is, that I have an account controller which manages login, register, etc. This controller is instanstiated when the page loads. with that instance I also have a instance of the UserManager class. In my admin controller I want to use that instance of the UserManager class and not create a new one as I'm currently doing. Hope this explains it a bit better

/edit2: As requested the code snippets. What I want to do is to take the UserContext instance from the AccountController class and use it in the AdminController class. I also might add that the connection to the database works fine. I can query everything. It's just that I'm reluctant to create another instance of the UserContext.

AccountController.cs:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new UserContext())))
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
    // Additional GET/POST/PUT/DELETE methods
```

AdminController.cs

```
/// <summary>The admin controller.</summary>
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private UserContext userContext = new UserContext();

    public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    public ActionResult ManageUser()
    {
        var users = this.userContext.Users.ToList();

        return this.PartialView(users);
    }
```

UserContext.cs

```
public class UserContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public UserContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-N44Web-20131104100543.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-N44Web-20131104100543;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different controllers should have different database context.
By default the lifetime of a MVC controller is equal to the Request and hence the Context can not and should not be used after a method on the controller is complete.

Instantiate a context in the constructor of the AdminController just like you already do in your AccountController.

Comment: Ok, will do that. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about user model which is modeled based on your database tables.
you will use a datacontext though to create the connection between your user model and the database table for users and by doing so you can create, update, remove user and etc.

you may create your data context through Entityframeworks, NHibernate, or other standard ORMS.

This is the core concept. If you provide more info I will be  able to help more.

Comment: The data-context and the connection to the database already exist. This is not the problem. My problem is, that I have an account controller which manages login, register, etc. This controller is instanstiated when the page loads. with that instance I also have a instance of the UserManager class. In my admin controller I want to use that instance of the UserManager class and not create a new one as I'm currently doing. Hope this explains it a bit better.